# Google Meet for iOS - URL Scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme, mdm, hangouts-api

Im trying to find the **URL Scheme Google Meet** for iOS:

```
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google-meet/id1013231476
```

I need to find it so i can link a MDM managed web browser to **Google Meet**, so related meeting invite links open in **Google Meet**.

I have downloaded the app to desktop, located the `info.plist` XML has the `CFBundleURLSchemes` as gmeet.

But i have tried putting `gmeet://` into my MDM browser whitelist, but opening a meeting invite, the **Google Meet** app does not open.

I just get sent to the iOS app store.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks! This helped me.

I was looking for the Meet callback URL, and your question is the only place that lists it correctly.

I'm using it successfully in the IOS shortcuts App, to open a daily meeting for me.

URL

```
gmeet://meeting-id-here
```

then Safari

```
OPEN URL
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! =) If your message doesn't contain direct answer, please post it in comments to the questions. It would be easier to find right answer for other users.